# Looping RecordSet Destination in SSIS Script Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How to loop through / access values of RecordSet Destination in SSIS Script Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok got this done as

```
        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["containerHeader"].Value);
```

once datatable is filled can do looping on it.

Comment: I tried this in a Script Component but it does not recognize `Dts.Variables`. Any idea on this?